# '1' is null or no object ... again

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have this piece of JS that throws the mentioned error (IE8 & 7). I have looked a thousand times for a trailing comma and cannot find it - may be the problem is elsewhere? Any help would be appreciated.

```
ts.addParser({
id: 'customDate',
is: function(s) {
  return false;
},
format: function(s) {
  var date = s.match(/^\s(\w{1,2})[.](\d{1,2})[.](\d{4})[,]\s(\d{1,2})[:](\d{1,2})\s\bUhr\b\s$/);

  var day = String(date[1]);
  var month = String(date[2]);
  var year = String(date[3]);
  var hour = String(date[4]);
  var minute = String(date[5]);
  return '' + year + month + day + hour + minute;
},  type: 'numeric'   
});
```

Comment: What is "ts" a reference to?  The error is happening inside that "addParser" function, and without seeing that it's going to be hard to say what the problem is.

Comment: The error is happening right here: var day = String(date[1]);
ts refers to Tablesorter plugin.

Comment: should it not be `date[0]`, `date[1]`, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the regex match fails `date` will be `null`. So

```
var day = String(date[1]);
```

will fail.

Add a check:

```
if (date === null) // return error or some default
```

Comment: The regex match does not fail and date is not null. Any other ideas ?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. It seems IE7 didn't like that regex after all, thanks to another bug - http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-lookahead-bug